# Why do these two integer variables and two double variables (seemingly) share the same address in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I wrote a simple program that has a method for printing the address of a variable and the contents stored in that address, just to help me understand pointers a little bit better:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type Variable);


/* Entry point */
int main()
{
    int IntegerVariable1 = 5;
    int IntegerVariable2 = 6;

    double FloatingVariable1 = 10;
    double FloatingVariable2 = 11;

    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(IntegerVariable1);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(IntegerVariable2);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(FloatingVariable1);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(FloatingVariable2);
}


/* Prints the address and the corresponding contents of a given variable */
template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type Variable)
{
    Type* Pointer = &Variable;

    cout << "Address: " << Pointer << endl;
    cout << "Contents: " << *Pointer << endl;
}
```

When I ran this on Visual Studio, I got the following output:

```
Address: 008FFB88
Contents: 5
Address: 008FFB88
Contents: 6
Address: 008FFB84
Contents: 10
Address: 008FFB84
Contents: 11
```

As you can see, the first two integers seem to have the same address of 008FFB88; likewise, the two floating pointer variables have the same address of 008FFB84.

Is there a flaw in my program, or am I missing some key knowledge for understanding what's going on here?

Comment: Because you print the address of the local stack variable `Variable` which is not the address of the variable that you passed. You have to pass the address via pointer: "Call by Reference" is the keyword!

Comment: You are taking an address, of a local variable, which are just copies of your original ones. And those copies seems to be put in the same memory location on each invocation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is you are printing the address of `Variable`, not the address of the variables from main.  The address of `Variable` is independent of the address of the variable you initialize it from and can be the same address through multiple calls to the function.

If we take a reference instead, which give us an alias to the actual variable and not a copy like:

```
template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type& Variable)
{
    Type* Pointer = &Variable;

    cout << "Address: " << Pointer << endl;
    cout << "Contents: " << *Pointer << endl;
}
```

[then we see the addresses are indeed different](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bef0e8171dcf91f)

```
Address: 0x7fffc8386ce8
Contents: 5
Address: 0x7fffc8386cec
Contents: 6
Address: 0x7fffc8386cf0
Contents: 10
Address: 0x7fffc8386cf8
Contents: 11
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. So with pass-by-reference, Variable will serve as an alias for the integers and doubles we pass in, and thus the addresses will be different. I tried changing my code to reflect this, but I get the error "cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'. Not quite sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: @AleksandrH You either need `void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type& Variable)` or if you use `PrintAddressAndContentsOf(const Type & Variable);` you need to change `Type* Pointer = &Variable;` to `const Type* Pointer = &Variable;`

Comment: Thanks! Strange, my method signature is simply `void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type& Variable)` without the keyword `const`. But changing the first line to `const Type* Pointer = &Variable` did the trick.

Comment: @AleksandrH Weird.  That shouldn't be needed with a non const reference and it compiler fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bef0e8171dcf91f) without `const Type* Pointer = &Variable;`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems Visual Studio was just being stupid. I re-copied the signature to the method prototype, removed const, and it compiled just fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

> As you can see, the first two integers seem to have the same address of 008FFB88; likewise, the two floating pointer variables have the same address of 008FFB84.

Those are the addresses of the variable in the function in multiple invocations of the function. They are not the addresses of the variables in the calling function. If you want to examine the addresses of the variables in the calling function, you can do that using couple of methods:

1. change the function to accept a pointer and pass the addresses of the variables to the function.
2. change the function to accept a reference and pass the variables just as you have to the function.

---

**Option 1**

```
// Function declaration
template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type* variableAddress);

// Usage
PrintAddressAndContentsOf(&IntegerVariable1);
```

**Option 2**

```
// Function declaration
template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type& variableReference);

// Usage
PrintAddressAndContentsOf(IntegerVariable1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the address of the copy of the variables that is pushed onto the stack. Your template passes `Variable' by value.

You should expect (though in no way rely on) subsequent calls to a function from within a given function to push the arguments to the same addresses. Calls to different functions will start from the same point.

Furthermore the difference of 4 bytes is because int is 4 bytes and double is 8 bytes on your platform. Counter-intuitively it is common and again true for you that the stack is 'upside down' in address space. 'pushing' variables on the stack actually moves the top of the stack down.

Try the following. All the addresses should be different.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type* Pointer);


/* Entry point */
int main()
{
    int IntegerVariable1 = 5;
    int IntegerVariable2 = 6;

    double FloatingVariable1 = 10;
    double FloatingVariable2 = 11;

    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(&IntegerVariable1);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(&IntegerVariable2);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(&FloatingVariable1);
    PrintAddressAndContentsOf(&FloatingVariable2);
}


/* Prints the address and the corresponding contents of a given variable */
template<typename Type>
void PrintAddressAndContentsOf(Type* Pointer)
{
    cout << "Address: " << Pointer << endl;
    cout << "Contents: " << *Pointer << endl;
}
```

Comment: The part about the 4-byte difference being reflected in the memory addresses is interesting. Thank you!